# Disable checkboxes when another checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to change the logic of this check-box, The check-box is sitting in an accordion, I want the check-box to disable other checkbook when I click on one check-box.

Here is my code below.

```js
$(function() {
  $(':checkbox').click(function() {
    // Uncheck any other checkboxes except this one
    $(':checkbox').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
  });
})

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">MEDIA</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="News" id="News" value="News" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="filter(this.value)" /> News</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="OfficialStatement" id="OfficialStatement" value="OfficialStatement" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="filter(this.value)" /> Official Statements</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="Speeches" id="Speeches" value="Speeches" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="filter(this.value)" /> Speech</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="PressRelease" id="PressRelease" value="PressRelease" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="filter(this.value)" /> Press Release</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="Communiques" id="Communiques" value="Communiques" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="filter(this.value)" /> Communique</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="PressConference" id="PressConference" value="PressConference" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="filter(this.value)" /> Press Conference</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="Interviews" id="Interviews" value="Interviews" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="filter(this.value)" /> Interviews</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="SuccessStories" id="SuccessStories" value="SuccessStories" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="filter(this.value)" /> Success Stories</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="SocialMedia" id="SocialMedia" value="SocialMedia" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="filter(this.value)" /> Social Media</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="PressContact" id="PressContact" value="PressContact" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="filter(this.value)" /> Press Contacts</p>
</div>
</div>
<!--right-right-->

</div>
<!--right-->
```

I will really appreciate your assistance. I have been on this for the past one week.

Comment: Your code correctly unchecks all other checked boxes, ensuring only one remains checked. Do you want to actually disable all other boxes from being clickable when one is clicked? That is kind of counter user-intuitive.

Comment: Yes exactly what i want. I want the rest check-box not to be click-able after a check-box is click.

Comment: you would be better off using `radio`; if you are only wanting one (and only one) list of items to be selected. even a `select` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

First, give all `checkboxes` of the same group, a same class. Then use the following JQuery code to simulate `checkboxes` as `radio buttons`. See the code snippet below:

```js
$( 'input:checkbox' ).on( 'change', function () {
  var $elm = $( this ),
      group = 'input:checkbox[class="' + $elm.attr(  'class' ) + '"]';

  $( group ).not( this ).prop( 'checked', false );
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(140px, 1fr))
}
p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li class="panel">
        <p><b>Group 1:</b></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="News" value="News"/><label for="News"> News</label></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="OfficialStatement" value="OfficialStatement"/><label for="OfficialStatement"> Official Statements</label></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="Speeches" value="Speeches"/><label for="Speeches"> Speech</label></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="PressRelease" value="PressRelease"/><label for="PressRelease"> Press Release</label></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="Communiques" value="Communiques"/><label for="Communiques"> Communique</label></p>
    </li>
    <li class="panel">
        <p><b>Group 2:</b></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="group2" id="PressConference" value="PressConference"/><label for="PressConference"> Press Conference</label></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="group2" id="Interviews" value="Interviews"/><label for="Interviews"> Interviews</label></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="group2" id="SuccessStories" value="SuccessStories"/><label for="SuccessStories"> Success Stories</label></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="group2" id="SocialMedia" value="SocialMedia"/><label for="SocialMedia"> Social Media</label></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="group2" id="PressContact" value="PressContact"/><label for="PressContact"> Press Contacts</label></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or if you have only one group of check boxes, you can simply do this:

```js
$( 'input:checkbox' ).on( 'change', function () {
  $( 'input:checkbox').not( this ).prop( 'checked', false );
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel">
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="News" value="News"/><label for="News"> News</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="OfficialStatement" value="OfficialStatement"/><label for="OfficialStatement"> Official Statements</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="Speeches" value="Speeches"/><label for="Speeches"> Speech</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="PressRelease" value="PressRelease"/><label for="PressRelease"> Press Release</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="Communiques" value="Communiques"/><label for="Communiques"> Communique</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="group2" id="PressConference" value="PressConference"/><label for="PressConference"> Press Conference</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="group2" id="Interviews" value="Interviews"/><label for="Interviews"> Interviews</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="group2" id="SuccessStories" value="SuccessStories"/><label for="SuccessStories"> Success Stories</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="group2" id="SocialMedia" value="SocialMedia"/><label for="SocialMedia"> Social Media</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="group2" id="PressContact" value="PressContact"/><label for="PressContact"> Press Contacts</label></p>
</div>
```